# opening a text file, converting it to string, and then outputing the string to another text file, produces unwanted \n's as well as some other stuff

Tags: text, c++-cli, type-conversion, output

I've asked this before, but the results were not fruitful, i don't know whether i should've bumped it so i just made a new one.

my code for opening the text file and converting it to stringstream:

```
OpenFileDialog^ failas = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
failas->Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
if( failas->ShowDialog() != System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
{
    return;
}
MessageBox::Show( failas->FileName );

String^ str = failas->FileName;
StreamReader ^strm = gcnew StreamReader(str);
String ^ST1=strm->ReadToEnd();
strm->Close();
string st1 = marshal_as<string,String ^>(ST1);

stringstream SS(st1);
```

if i were to output the SS or st1
instead of outputting something like:

```
a
a
a
```

I get

```
a

a

a
```

And now the thing is, that if i open the file in notepad, it looks like intended(no spaces between lines) but if i load it anywhere else but there, it still has the spaces.

I was understand this has something to do with the way windows save text files, but I have no idea how to remove the additional `\n` when I use the command ReadToEnd?

any ideas?

Comment: Your code is C++/CLI not Standard C++. In the future please make sure you tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the input file using .Net methods, converting it to an unmanaged C++ stringstream, and then presumably writing the output file using unmanaged C++ methods.

In C++, many methods will automatically handle Windows vs. Unix line endings: `fprintf(outfile, "Some text\n");` will actually write the bytes `"Some text\r\n"` to disk, if the file was opened in text mode.

You didn't say how you're writing the output file, but I think what's happening is that you're using `fopen` or similar in text mode. When you read from the input file, it contained CR-LF (`\r\n`) character sequences, and those character sequences were copied to the `String^ ST1`. They were still there when you copied the characters to the `stringstream`.

When you wrote the `"\r\n"` using `fwrite` or similar, it converted the `\n` to `\r\n`, resulting in `\r\r\n` sequences. This is not a standard line-ending on any platform, so that's why different editors are displaying it differently. You can confirm this by looking at the output file in a binary editor (rename to *.bin and open in Visual Studio): I expect you'll see bytes `0d 0d 0a` at the end of each line.

To fix this, there's a couple things you can do:

- You could read the file using unmanaged methods. Since you apparently want to manipulate and write using unmanaged, you can stay in unmanaged-land for the whole operation. Let the unmanaged APIs convert the `\r\n` on disk to `\n` in memory, and convert back to `\r\n` when written back to disk.
- You could remove the `\r` characters from the string after reading in .Net, before writing in unmanaged C++. This would be a simple call to [`String::Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).
- You could open the file for writing in unmanaged C++ as a binary file, rather than text. This will turn off the line-ending conversion, and output exactly the characters you have in your string. Just be sure to use `\r\n` line endings if you manipulate the data before writing it.